# What happened to the nuclear bomb headed for New York City?

Tags: jericho-tv-series

The fate of [Robert Hawkins'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Hawkins_%28Jericho_character%29#Robert_Hawkins) nuclear bomb is a central plot element of the [TV series Jericho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jericho_%28TV_series%29) because it could be used to identify the perpetrators of the nuclear attack.

Early on in the series it is revealed that New York City had saved itself from the bomb sent to destroy the city.  New York's heightened alertness and security allowed them to detect the bomb before the terrorists could deliver it.

So that begs the question, why can't the bomb seized in New York be used to identify the perpetrators of the conspiracy.  Did the bomb detonate at some point?

Is it because Texas would not be willing to believe the remaining United States even if they had the bomb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The people in Jericho were still independent, which is why Texas trusted them.  They weren't allied with either government that was trying to take over.  (Additionally, I vaguely recall either Jake or Hawkins having a high-ranking contact inside Texas that trusted them)

As for the bomb itself - I see two possibilities:

> * [Thomas Valente](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Jericho_characters#Thomas_Valente) was very high-ranking in the Department of Homeland Security - and one of the men responsible for the attack.  It doesn't seem like too much of a stretch for him to use his contacts to bury it before its origin could be confirmed.  ([Here's his page, with a picture, on the Jericho wikia, in case you've forgotten his face](http://jericho.wikia.com/wiki/Thomas_Valente))
>  * One of the characters was incorrect.  [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locations_in_Jericho_%28TV_series%29), the Chinese broadcast in episode 3 mentioned that New York (纽约) was attacked, but in episode 7, Gray Anderson returns and mentions that New York survived.  Episode 18 also confirms over radio that New York was spared.  This ambiguity could have been 1) a mistake, 2) intentional to keep viewer off-guard, or 3) a clue to a plot element that had to be cut due to the series being canceled (twice).

Comment: Your second spoiler point is a little unclear, it seems like your suggesting that New York was not a target or was not attacked.  But we know that New York City was a target because of the radio communication that warned they were using FBI badges when the terrorists were caught (the same badges Hawkins was given by his terror cell, i believe).  So I don't understand where you are saying there is ambiguity.  Nothing in the series story has contradicted that New York City was both a target and was able to stop the attack by apprehending the attackers.

Comment: @MarkRogers Except for the news report, which gives the impression that _something_ happened in the vicinity of New York.  Maybe the bomb did go off, but after the others and not _in_ the city, but close enough that they thought it was attacked.  If so, there wouldn't be a bomb to analyze.

Comment: "Gray reports the capture of three men in a rental truck who were in possession of a 20-kiloton nuclear device in a steel drum".  While the story is chaotic earlier on to reflect the national state, it seems pretty clear that New York survived and furthermore the bomb was discovered and removed before detonation.

Answer (score 1):

sorry to butt in, but I do definitely recall the Cheyenne guys pinning the Bombs on North Korea and Iran presumably based on 'evidence' from an inspection of the New York Bomb, so it most likely survived the September Attacks and was then disposed of to conceal the actual point of origin.

Comment: I don't think Cheyenne controlled the actions of the East Coast in anyway because Cheyenne didn't think cities there would survive.  Once New York survived it broke with Cheyenne and began resisting them.  It's unlikely they would have destroyed the bomb at Cheyenne request.

Answer (score 0):

This is a BIG plot hole in Jericho and you're all right to point it out. The last "MacGuffin" of the series is Hawkins' unused bomb, which was intended to destroy Columbus, Ohio. Of course, our hero Hawkins decides to pick up his family instead of killing 1 million people and oblivious Columbus becomes the new capital. This legitimate Federal government controls the eastern USA, including the spared NYC. So this all begs the question: why hasn't the Columbus government pinned the attacks on the "Allied States" pretender-government in Cheyenne, citing the evidence of the un-detonated New York bomb? There is no reason to believe the NYC bomb and Hawkins' device are different, so presumably they both contain the same evidence implicating the Dick Cheney fan-club in the attacks. A one-line explanation of the New York bomb could've taken care of this, say mentioning that communication with the east was sketchy, or that the Columbus government had the bomb but then mysteriously lost it. Honestly, this plot hole highlights an overall problem in the series. One gets the feeling the creators didn't really know who would be pinned for the attacks, but knew Hawkins would be connected, and made the rest up as they went along. The NYC oversight is one big example of how rushed plot-lines or brushed-aside details (like the largest city in the country being spared from a nation-wide nuclear attack) can scramble an otherwise creative TV series.

Comment: How is this an answer? Might I suggest checking out the [Tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better idea of how to ask and answer questions here? We're not a discussion forum.